# Full phrase search

Tags: 7, search

Now I'm using "Search_api" module and when I input, for example, "test case" - it's output all articles which consists both of this words separately. But I want to make search with exact phrase "test case".
How can I do it? Maybe there is another module, or I can rework this one?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom view to override/bypass the default Drupal search form.

In the view, setup an exposed filter for the search phrase (appearing in either a specific field or combined set of fields), with the operator set to "CONTAINS ALL WORDS."  For a breakdown of the differences between "Contains" and "Contains Any Word", see https://www.drupal.org/node/1744880

One thing to consider when setting up this search form and exposing it is user intent- how likely is the user searching the site going to know exact phrasing?
You might want to use "Contains any word".

For an example of building a custom search form with multiple field search via views, see this ["Views Exposed Filters Multiple Field Search" blog post](https://swsblog.stanford.edu/blog/views-exposed-filters-multiple-field-search).

Answer (score -1):

Stepwise answer is as follows -

1. Go to your view
2. Go to your exposed filter field - which is showing filter on the page
3. Select "Contains all Words" operator

please have look on this link [Using views exposed filter](https://redcrackle.com/blog/using-views-exposed-filter-drupal-8)